# Postgresql table listed but not selectable

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Given a postgresql database, when the `\d+` command is employed the *references* table from below is nicely listed, as you can see:

```
 Schema |        Name         |   Type   |   Owner  |    Size    |  
--------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+---       
 ...
 public | references          | table    | user1    | 34 MB      |     
 public | references_id_seq   | sequence | user1    | 8192 bytes |
 ...
 (13 rows)
```

However, when I try to perform a SELECT operation on it, e.g., `SELECT * FROM references;` I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM references;
                      ^
```

However, the following works:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('references'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 79 MB
(1 row)
```

Is it a special kind of table? Why isn't it accessible? All the other tables from the database are "selectable".

As a side node, why is the size different (34 MB for `\d+' and 79 MB for pg_size_pretty)?

Comment: I've figured it out: **references** is a reserved keyword, i.e., it should be employed using `"references"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing with schema name also helps. For example:

```
select * from public.references;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `REFERENCES` is an SQL keyword, used for defining foreign key constraints:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM pg_get_keywords() WHERE word ILIKE 'references';
┌────────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│    word    │ catcode │ catdesc  │
├────────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ references │ R       │ reserved │
└────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
(1 row)
```

If you want to use it as an identifier, you have to double quote it:

```
SELECT * FROM "references";
```

But it is best to avoid such identifiers at all.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Do you have any idea why the table size is different for the 2 commands (34 MB for `\d+` and 79 MB for `pg_size_pretty`)?

Comment: That question is a bit unclear (`pg_size_pretty` doesn't measure anything), but `\dt+` and `pg_table_size` measure the same thing (table + associated TOAST table). Maybe you are seeing two different tables with the same name in different schemas.

Comment: My mistake with `pg_size_pretty`, I was referring to `pg_total_relation_size`. But now that you mentioned `pg_table_size`, this indeed gives the same result as `\d+`. Thanks! What's added extra in `pg_total_relation_size` that more than doubles the size?

Comment: @Mihai: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE

Comment: `pg_total_relation_size` counts the table's indexes too.